# MySQL: How do I merge two count queries?

Tags: mysql

How can I run these queries as a single query?

```
SELECT count(url) as t1 from shop_links
```

and

```
SELECT count(url) as t2 from shop_links where status = 3
```

I would like t1 and t2 in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(url)                  AS t1,
    COUNT(IF(status = 3, 1, NULL)) AS t2
FROM shop_links
```

If records status is 3, the IF will return value for COUNT() to count, if it is not 3 it returns NULL with COUNT will skip counting that record

Comment: What is 1 and NULL here?

Comment: @Volatil3 I have added explanation, you can give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Please do like this way

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT count(url) as t1 from shop_links) as cnt1,
  (SELECT count(url) as t2 from shop_links where status = 3) as cnt2
```

Comment: It is summing up? I do not need to sum

Comment: Ohh okay to let me update my ans

Comment: @Volatil3 Answer is updated now. Please check now.

Comment: `Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT count(url) as t2 from shop_links where status = 3) as cnt2 LIMIT 1000' at line 3`

Comment: Just missed comma, @Volatil3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(url) as t1, count(url) as t2 from shop_links where t2.status = 3
```